# How to submit input values with php depending on what input values are showing based off of a drop down selection

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, drop-down-menu

I currently have working code for the drop down selecting and using JavaScript to show/hide values depending on what has been selected as you can see with the code below. What I am trying to do is there are three different form inputs depending on select of New and used. If you select used it goes right to a form with input to enter. If you pick new it brings up another drop down where you select leased or purchased and depending on that select two other forms show. I know how to submit a form just one form to php using POST. But, my question is since depending on the drop down the form changes with different inputs. How can I submit this using php. My code is below there is three files the newform.php, newForm.js, and newformprocess.php. Again sending the form if it doesn't change I know what to do. What I am having trouble with is that the form changes depending on the drop down(s) selected. Many Many thanks for any help. Thank you all. Also the newformprocess.php file I know it doesn't look correct with the $_POST values etc. this is the code I wanted to use so I was missing around with.

First file newform.php

```
<?php include('formProcess.php'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Offer Submission Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/newForm.js"></script>
  </head>

<body>
 <div class="form-style-10">
        <h2>Please Select Your Offer Type</h2>
  <div class="inner-wrap">

   <form action="newformprocess.php" method="post">

    <label>Dealership Name:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="fin_dealerName" name="input_1" type="text" placeholder="Dealership Name" />

    <label>Which Marketing Medium?<em class="required-star">*</em></label><select id="market" type="select" name="marketing">
        <option id="market1" value="marketpick1">Facebook</option>
        <option id="market2" value="marketpick2">Website Banner</option>
        <option id="market3" value="marketpick3">Radio</option>
        <option id="market4" value="marketpick4">TV</option>
        <option id="market5" value="marketpick5">Email</option>
        <option id="market6" value="marketpick6">Direct Mail</option>
        <option id="market7" value="marketpick7">All Channels</option>
    </select>

    <label>Offer Type?</label><select id="newused" type="select" name="offerType">
        <option id="option_1" value="option1">New</option>
        <option id="option_2" value="option2">Used</option>
    </select>

<div id="new" style="display:none;">
    <label>Type of Purchase?</label><select id="newPick" type="select" name="typeOfPurchase">
        <option id="newPick_1" value="newPick1">Purchased</option>
        <option id="newPick_2" value="newPick2">Leased</option>
    </select>
</div>

    <!--This div section is for when client select puchased as their new opiton....--->
    <div id="purchased" style="display:none;">
        <label>Start Date:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="fin_startDate" name="input_2" type="text" placeholder="01/01/2012"/>
        <label>End Date:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="fin_endDate" name="input_3" type="text" placeholder="05/07/2015"/>
        <label>Year:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="fin_vehicleYear" name="input_4" type="text" placeholder="Vehicle Year"/>
        <label>Make:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="fin_make" name="input_5" type="text" placeholder="Make"/>
        <label>Model:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="fin_model" name="input_6" type="text" placeholder="Model"/>
        <label>Trim:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="fin_trim" name="input_7" type="text" placeholder="Trim of Vehicle"/>
        <label>Model #:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="fin_input_5" name="input_8" type="text" placeholder="14325"/>
        <label>Stock #:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="fin_input_5" name="input_9" type="text" placeholder="1234"/>
        <label>MSRP:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="fin_input_5" name="input_10" type="text" placeholder="$15,995"/>
        <label>Selling Price:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="fin_input_5" name="input_11" type="text" placeholder="$12,895"/>
        <label>Down Payment:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="fin_input_5" name="input_12" type="text" placeholder="$1,000"/>
        <label>$XXX/ Monthly Payment:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="fin_input_5" name="input_13" type="text" placeholder="$198"/>
        <label>Last 6 of VIN:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="fin_input_5" name="input_14" type="text" placeholder="123456"/>
        <label>Rebate:</label><input id="fin_input_5" name="input_15" type="text" placeholder="Rebate on Vehicle"/>
        <label>APR:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="fin_input_5" name="input_16" type="text" placeholder="ARP on Vehicle"/>
        <label>Term:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="fin_input_5" name="input_17" type="text" placeholder="Residual Payment on Vehicle"/>
        <label>Other Notes(Rebate Info, Special Details etc):</label> <textarea id="fin_textArea" name="input_18" placeholder="Notes" rows=2></textarea>
    </div>

    <!--This div section is for when client select leased as their new opiton....--->
    <div id="leased" style="display:none;">
        <label>Start Date:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="fin_startDate" name="input_2" type="text" placeholder="01/01/2012"/>
        <label>End Date:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="fin_endDate" name="input_3" type="text" placeholder="05/07/2015"/>
        <label>Year:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="fin_vehicleYear" name="input_4" type="text" placeholder="Vehicle Year"/>
        <label>Make:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="fin_make" name="input_5" type="text" placeholder="Make"/>
        <label>Model:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="fin_model" name="input_6" type="text" placeholder="Model"/>
        <label>Trim:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="fin_trim" name="input_7" type="text" placeholder="Trim of Vehicle"/>
        <label>Model #:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="fin_input_5" name="input_8" type="text" placeholder="14325"/>
        <label>Stock #:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="fin_input_5" name="input_9" type="text" placeholder="1234"/>
        <label>MSRP:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="fin_input_5" name="input_10" type="text" placeholder="$15,995"/>
        <label>Selling Price:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="fin_input_5" name="input_11" type="text" placeholder="$12,895"/>
        <label>Down Payment:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="fin_input_5" name="input_12" type="text" placeholder="$1,000"/>
        <label>$XXX/ Monthly Payment:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="fin_input_5" name="input_13" type="text" placeholder="$198"/>
        <label>Last 6 of VIN:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="fin_input_5" name="input_14" type="text" placeholder="123456"/>
        <label>Rebate:</label><input id="fin_input_5" name="input_15" type="text" placeholder="Rebate on Vehicle"/>
        <label>Term:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="fin_input_5" name="input_16" type="text" placeholder="ARP on Vehicle"/>
        <label>Residual Value:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="fin_input_5" name="input_17" type="text" placeholder="Residual Payment on Vehicle"/>
        <label>Miles Per Year:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="fin_input_5" name="input_17" type="text" placeholder="Residual Payment on Vehicle"/>
        <label>Other Notes(Rebate Info, Special Details etc):</label> <textarea id="fin_textArea" name="input_18" placeholder="Notes" rows=2></textarea>
    </div>

    <!-- IF users picks USED it will go to this section of the form...-->
    <div id="used" style="display:none;">
        <label>Start Date:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="fin_startDate" name="input_2" type="text" placeholder="01/01/2012"/>
        <label>End Date:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="fin_endDate" name="input_3" type="text" placeholder="05/07/2015"/>
        <label>Year:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="fin_vehicleYear" name="input_4" type="text" placeholder="Vehicle Year"/>
        <label>Make:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="fin_make" name="input_5" type="text" placeholder="Make"/>
        <label>Model:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="fin_model" name="input_6" type="text" placeholder="Model"/>
        <label>Trim:</label><input id="fin_trim" name="input_7" type="text" placeholder="Trim of Vehicle"/>
        <label>Stock #:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="fin_input_5" name="input_9" type="text" placeholder="1234"/>
        <label>Selling Price:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="fin_input_5" name="input_11" type="text" placeholder="$12,895"/>
        <label>Down Payment:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="fin_input_5" name="input_12" type="text" placeholder="$1,000"/>
        <label>APR:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="fin_input_5" name="input_16" type="text" placeholder="ARP on Vehicle"/>
        <label>Term:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="used_term" name="input_14" type="text" placeholder=""/>
        <label>Other Notes(Rebate Info, Special Details etc):</label><textarea id="fin_textArea" name="input_18" placeholder="Notes" rows=2></textarea>
    </div>

        <div class="button-section"><br />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Offer" />
        </div>

    </form>
</body>
  </div>
</div>
</html>
```

second file newForm.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$select = $('#newused');
$('#newused').on('mousedown',function(){

    if($(this).val() == "option1"){
        if($('#new').is(":hidden")){
            $('#new').show();
        }        
        $('#used').hide();

    }

    if($(this).val() == "option2"){
        if($('#used').is(":hidden")){
            $('#used').show();
        }
       $('#new').hide();
       $('#leased').hide(); 
       $('#purchased').hide();
    }

});


$select = $('#newPick');
$('#newPick').on('mousedown',function(){

    if($(this).val() == "newPick1"){
        if($('#purchased').is(":hidden")){
            $('#purchased').show();
        }        
        $('#leased').hide(); 
        $('#used').hide();
    }

        if($(this).val() == "newPick2"){
        if($('#leased').is(":hidden")){
            $('#leased').show();
        }        
        $('#purchased').hide(); 
        $('#used').hide();
    }

    });
    });
```

Last file newformprocess.php

```
<?php 

        if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
        {

            // Checking For Blank Fields....
            if($_POST['offerType']==""|| $_POST['typeOfPurchase'] =="" ||$_POST['marketing']==""||$_POST['input_1']==""||$_POST['input_2']==""||$_POST['input_3']==""||$_POST['input_4']==""||$_POST['input_5']==""||
            $_POST['input_6']==""||$_POST['input_7']==""||$_POST['input_9']==""||$_POST['input_10']==""||$_POST['input_11']==""||$_POST['input_12']==""||$_POST['input_13']==""||$_POST['input_14']=="")
                { 
?>
                    <script>
                        alert("Please complete the text marked with an *.");
                    </script>
<?php
                }

        else{

            $Offer = $_POST['offerType'];
            $typeOfpurchase = $_POST['typeOfPurchase'];
            $Marketing = $_POST['marketing'];
            $Field1 = $_POST['input_1'];
            $Field2 = $_POST['input_2'];
            $Field3 = $_POST['input_3'];
            $Field4 = $_POST['input_4'];
            $Field5 = $_POST['input_5'];
            $Field6 = $_POST['input_6'];
            $Field7 = $_POST['input_7'];
            $Field8 = $_POST['input_8'];
            $Field9 = $_POST['input_9'];
            $Field10 = $_POST['input_10'];
            $Field11 = $_POST['input_11'];
            $Field12 = $_POST['input_12'];
            $Field13 = $_POST['input_13'];
            $Field14 = $_POST['input_14'];
            $Field15 = $_POST['input_15'];
            $Field16 = $_POST['input_16'];
            $Field17 = $_POST['input_17'];
            $message = $_POST['input_18'];
            $message = wordwrap($message, 70);
            $form_content = 
            "What Type of Offer: $Offer
            If your purhcase was new what was your type of purchase: $typeOfpurchase
            Which Marketing Medium: $Marketing
            Dealership Name: $Field1
            Offer Start Date: $Field2
            Offer End Date: $Field3
            Year of Vehicle: $Field4
            Make of Vehicle: $Field5
            Model of Vehicle: $Field6
            Trim of Vehicle: $Field7
            Model # Vehicle: $Field8 
            Stock # of Vehicle: $Field9
            MSRP of Vehicle: $Field10
            Selling Price of Vehicle: $Field11
            Down Payment on Vehicle: $Field12
            XXX/ Month on Vehicle: $Field13
            Last 6 of VIN on Vehicle: $Field14
            Rebate on Vehicle: $Field15
            APR on Vehicle: $Field16 
            Residual Payment on Vehicle: $Field17 
            Other Notes (Rebate Info, Special Details etc): $message";

            $email_subject = "Online Offer Submission Form";

            $arrEmail = array('Jonathan <myemail@myemail.com?>');


                foreach($arrEmail as $key => $email_to)
                mail($email_to, $email_subject, $form_content);

                header('location: http://www.mydealerworld.com/thank-you-for-contacting-dealer-world/');
    }
        }
```

Comment: If you submit the fields without them 'existing' on the page, they will simply show up as blanks in the insert. You can also check for the presence of the `$_POST` with `isset($_POST['parameter'])`. Can you not just submit the forms 'normally'? I'm afraid I'm struggling to see the issue. Do you have different form `action=` URLs?

Comment: @ObsidianAge thank you for your insight. I didn't even think of that I mean I was wondering if they would be sent as blank. The only thing I guess would be the issue now is I don't want all the blank fields to be sent by email. Ok, say it is for a USED car which only has 12 input fields total  but, say the new purchased fields has 18 and some of the input fields are different. How can I remove the non related fields to be sent by email. The email sending part etc. I know how to do that already. Can I use some type of catch so that it only sends the input fields of the used drop down select.

Comment: @ObsidianAge basically I guess what I am saying is when I make sure fields are not blank and also storing the $_POST['value'] into a variable would I do this the normal way say like I have above in the newformprocess.php file.  And no matter what when the form is submitted say one of the $_POST that stores to a variable if it doesn't have anything in the $_POST['value'] it would just be blank correct. I am sorry hope I am making this clear enough. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: I still cannot get this to work correctly. In the validation part where it checks for blank fields I removed because with selection NEW and either LEASED or PURCHASED it continued to throw errors no matter what. So I simply left just one validation in it and that is the dealers name. Anyways when I pick USED and submit the form I get all the values but, when I submit form with the NEW selection and then either PUCHASED or LEASED I only get the first few values like dealer name, type of purchase, and offer everything else is blank.     Can anyone please explain why and any other issues they see

Comment: @ObsidianAge No different action URLs the form goes to php page where it does the validation etc. But, I used the isset($_POST['parameter']) actually multiple ones at that because there are a few that need to be filled in. Anyways the problem I am having now is when I hit submit say for a new purchase type some of the fields are empty when the email is sent to me. And some of the fields not being sent are fields that need to be filled in for each purchase type. Meaning it is not a hidden field either so it should display but, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can send values of inputs with AJAX requests. After you assign variables with Javascript, just send them with ajax request. (e.g. `var your_assigned_variable = input.val()`)

```
$.ajax({
'url':'newformprocess.php',
'type':'post',
'data':{'submit':true,'another_key':your_assigned_variable},
success:function(){
//when successfully sent
},
error:function(){
//if an ajax error occures, do something
}
});
```

See more:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: this is all being done in WordPress now I have used AJAX calls before in my dashboard I built just never with WordPress by chance would you happen to know if adding AJAX to WordPress is difficult or just something basic like adding JS and PHP.